# Autodetect return type of template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a some classes with a function. In all classes the function has the same name and argument type but different return type. I need a some template function which can automagically detect correct template substitution without angle brackets.

Test code to illustrate question:

```
struct Float
{
    static Float convert(int i)
    {
        return Float{static_cast<float>(i)};
    }

    float _f;
};

struct Int
{
    static Int convert(int i)
    {
        return Int{i};
    }

    int _i;
};

template<typename T>
T convert(int i)
{
    return T::convert(i);
}


int main()
{
    Float f1 = convert<Float>(10);
    Int i1 = convert<Int>(10);

    // Float f2 = convert(10); compilation error
    // Int i2 = convert(10); compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. templates makes me crazy I want but can't understand them.

Comment: Template choice "without angle brackets" requires *argument deduction*. The return type of a function is *not* an argument. So you can rest assured you can't get there from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it's a perfect fit to your needs, but you may simulate what you want with a class and a templated conversion operator:

```
class convert {
    int arg;
public:
    convert(int arg) : arg(arg) {}

    template<class T>
    operator T() const {
      return T::convert(arg);
    }
};
```

Since template argument deduction works for templated conversion operators, you can write this:

```
Float f1 = convert(10);
Int i1 = convert(10);
```

Just like you want.

Comment: Ho that's nice. It might be the only way to template a function to its return type. It's a good trick I'll remember.

Comment: Nice trick. Enough good for me. Only want to add that with this way `Float f1 = convert<Float>(10)` wont work. But it can be replaced with `Float f1 = static_cast<Float>(convert(10))`

Comment: @IvanRomanov - Well, yeah that's the long and short of it. You can have one but not the other, since now it's not a function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the convert function? You can use a single argument constructor to do the same job.

```
struct Float
{
    Float(int i)
    {
        _f =  static_cast<float>(i);
    }

    float _f;
};

struct Int
{
    Int(int i)
    {
        _i = static_cast<int>(i);
    }

    int _i;
};

int main()
{
    Float f2 = 10;
    Int i2   = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

If you're worried about the **implicit** calls to the constructor you can make it **explicit**

```
struct Float
{
    explicit Float(int i)
    {
        _f =  static_cast<float>(i);
    }

    float _f;
};

int main()
{
    Float f2 = Float(10);
    return 0;
}
```

The readability of the code is affected if the function with same name and the same type of input arguments can produce different return types.

Comment: I can't use constructors. Classes must supports aggregate initialization. Also I have many classes and I don't want to dublicate functional. Global `::convert` function does a common simple operation. `return T::convert(i * 2);` for example.